# Problems with save several images in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

I have problem with saving files in django. Pls can someone help me?

I have form with 2 fields: `description` and `image`. By image field user can load several images. To create image field I used [django-multiupload](https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload) app. Also I load data to server by ajax. I tried next code but it riase error. How to fix this problem? Problems with saving image files. From Traceback I understand that problem started in this line of view: `article = article_form.save(commit=False)`

**models.py:**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))

class Image(models.Model):
    article= models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(_('Image'), upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

**forms.py:**

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('description', )

    image = MultiFileField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['image']:
            Image.objects.create(image=each, article=instance)
        return instance
```

**views.py:**

```
def article_add(request, project_id):
    data = dict()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if article_form.is_valid():
            article = article_form.save(commit=False)
            article.project = project 
            article.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            articles = Article.objects.all
            context = {'articles': articles}
            context.update(csrf(request))
            data['html_article'] = render_to_string('project/article_list.html', context)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        article_form = ArticleForm()
    context = {'article_form': article_form}
    data['html_article_form'] = render_to_string('project/article_add.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var loadForm = function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr("data-url"),
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#modal").modal("show");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#modal .modal-content").html(data.html_article_form);
            }
        });
    };

    var saveForm = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        var dataForm = new FormData(form.get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: dataForm 
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#article-list").html(data.html_article);
                    $("#modal").modal("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $("#modal .modal-content").html(data.html_article_form);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    // Create Article
    $("#article-add-button").click(loadForm);
    $("#modal").on("submit", ".js-article-add-form", saveForm);

    // Update Article
    $("#article-list").on("click", "#js-edit-article-button", loadForm);
    $("#modal").on("submit", ".js-article-edit-form", saveForm);
});
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\reversion\revisions.py", line 296, in do_revision_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 1673, in article_add
    article = article_form.save(commit=False)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\forms.py", line 271, in save
    Image.objects.create(image=each, article=instance)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 399, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 539, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]�������� ���������� INSERT � ������������ FOREIGN KEY "project_image_article_id_1cd62783_fk_project_article_id". �������� ��������� � ���� ������ "RMS", ������� "dbo.project_article", column \'code\'. (547) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an intergrity error which shows that the foreign key does not exists. It stems from this code

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['image']:
        Image.objects.create(image=each, article=instance)
    return instance
```

The first time you call the form save method, you are doing so without the article being saved. Which means the article does not have a PK. Which in turn means that the image does not obey referential intergrity rules for it's foreign key.

I suggest you move this bit to your view it might look like this.

```
if article_form.is_valid(): 
        article = article_form.save(commit=False)
        article.project = project 
        article.save()
        for each in article_form.cleaned_data['image']:
            Image.objects.create(image=each, article=instance)
```

Make it execute after the article has been committed.

Comment: Hello! I also thought about moving code of creating image objects to view but dont understand how to make it correctly. I am really comfused. Can you show me how to make it? Just to add that code after `specification.save()` in view?

Comment: Yes, you was right. I did the same before your last update and solve my problem. Thank you anyway. I have other problem. I use the same form for editing article. The problem is there is no images in image field when I open my edit form but in the same time I see current data in descrtiption field. Can you help me to solve this new problem pls. I use in view: `article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=article)`

Comment: can you be so kind as to post a new question please with the updated code. Thanks

Comment: I asked new question as you adviced. Can you check it pls. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157139/problems-with-editind-multiupload-image-field